# javascript doesn't trigger until after search - Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a live search that is giving me a little bit trouble.  I'm rendering an index page using a live search to re-render the page based on the results. There are 2 different search critera, one is based on name, the other is based on a flag.

My .js file

```
$(function() {
  $("#beers").on('click', '.pagination a', function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
  $("#beers_search input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    $.get($("beers_search").attr("action"), $("#beers_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
  var options = {
    callback: function() {
      $.get($("beers_search").attr("action"), $("#beers_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    },
    wait: 750,
    highlight: false,
    captureLength: 1
  }
  $("#beers_search input").typeWatch( options );
});
```

As can be seen, I'm looking for either a `.change()` on a checkbox or monitoring the input field using `typeWatch`.  The problem is, a lot of times, it won't work unless I execute a search, then it works fine.  I read about the turbolinks causing things to screw up and I have the `//=require jquery.turbolinks` in my `application.js` file which solved a whole slew of other issues. I just don't understand why this doesn't work 100% of the time. I'm not even sure how to test it when it's not working to try and figure out why.  Any help would be appreciated.  I can supply any of the controller code or html code if need be, I just thought the only pertinent information was the .js

Comment: Hi, just a quick question.  Did you use a shared id "beers_search" on different inputs?  If so, that could be the cause, try giving the checkbox a different id.

Comment: I didn't, I used one ID for the entirety of the form
    <div class="center">
      <%= form_tag beers_path, :method => 'get', id: "beers_search", class:"form-inline" do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag(:hide_rated, "Hide rated beers") %><%= check_box_tag :hide_rated, class: "form-control" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

Comment: sorry that looks so jumbled.  Formatting didn't work.  Do you think I should give each input a specific ID and reference them instead?

Comment: I am not sure, but it is worth trying.  As now seeing from the js code the typeWatch binds to the checkBox as well.

Comment: Hi, is it working when page is being loaded first time but not working when page is rendered?

Comment: it seems to not work initially and then will work after a search, you can even go to a different page then back to the index page and it will still work, it's just some times on that initial visit to the page it doesn't work.